# Koajs and Socket.io integration

Tags: node.js, sockets, koa

Please, need help with integration of sockets with this  [koajs skeleton](https://github.com/danneu/koa-skeleton)

Here is the code from server side file (/src/index.js)

```
'use strict';

// 3rd party
require('dotenv').config(); // Load env vars from .env, always run this early
const koa = require('koa');
const bouncer = require('koa-bouncer');
const nunjucksRender = require('koa-nunjucks-render');
const debug = require('debug')('app:index');
// 1st party
const config = require('./config');
const mw = require('./middleware');
const belt = require('./belt');
const cancan = require('./cancan');

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const app = koa();
app.poweredBy = false;
app.proxy = config.TRUST_PROXY;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Configure view-layer (nunjucks)
//
// We can override options send directly to nunjucks.
// https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#configure
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const nunjucksOptions = {
  // `yield this.render('show_user')` will assume that a show_user.html exists
  ext: '.html',
  noCache: config.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  // don't throw template errors in development if we try to render
  // a null/undefined like {{ x }}. in theory, setting it to true prevents
  // bugs and forces you to be explicit about {{ x or '' }}, but in reality,
  // often more annoying than it's worth.
  throwOnUndefined: false,
  // globals are bindings we want to expose to all templates
  globals: {
    // let us use `can(USER, ACTION, TARGET)` authorization-checks in templates
    can: cancan.can,
  },
  // filters are functions that we can pipe values to from nunjucks templates.
  // e.g. {{ user.uname | md5 | toAvatarUrl }}
  filters: {
    json: x => JSON.stringify(x, null, '  '),
    formatDate: belt.formatDate,
    nl2br: belt.nl2br,
    md5: belt.md5,
    toAvatarUrl: belt.toAvatarUrl,
    autolink: belt.autolink,
  },
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Middleware
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.use(mw.ensureReferer());
app.use(require('koa-helmet')());
app.use(require('koa-compress')());
app.use(require('koa-static')('public'));
// Don't show logger in test mode
if (config.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  app.use(require('koa-logger')());
}
app.use(require('koa-body')({ multipart: true }));
app.use(mw.methodOverride());  // Must come after body parser
app.use(mw.removeTrailingSlash());
app.use(mw.wrapCurrUser());
app.use(mw.wrapFlash('flash'));
app.use(bouncer.middleware());
app.use(mw.handleBouncerValidationError()); // Must come after bouncer.middleware()
app.use(nunjucksRender('views', nunjucksOptions));

// Provide a convience function for protecting our routes behind
// our authorization rules. If authorization check fails, 404 response.
//
// Usage:
//
//    router.get('/topics/:id', function*() {
//      const topic = yield db.getTopicById(this.params.id);
//      this.assertAuthorized(this.currUser, 'READ_TOPIC', topic);
//      ...
//    });
app.use(function*(next) {
  this.assertAuthorized = (user, action, target) => {
    const isAuthorized = cancan.can(user, action, target);
    const uname = (user && user.uname) || '<Guest>';
    debug('[assertAuthorized] Can %s %s: %s', uname, action, isAuthorized);
    this.assert(isAuthorized, 404);
  };
  yield* next;
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Routes
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.use(require('./routes').routes());
app.use(require('./routes/authentication').routes());
app.use(require('./routes/admin').routes());

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// If we run this file directly (npm start, npm run start-dev, node src/index.js)
// then start the server. Else, if we require() this file (like from
// our tests), then don't start the server and instead just export the app.
if (require.main === module) {
  app.listen(config.PORT, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port', config.PORT);
  });
} else {
  module.exports = app;
}
```

On client side (/views/master.js) :

```
   .... 
   <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
   <script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
      console.log('received news with data: ');
      console.log(data);
    });

    function myclick () {
      console.log("click");
      socket.emit('click', { clickdata: 'someone clicked on the button' });
    }

  </script>
 <button type="button" onclick="myclick();">Click Me and watch console at server and in browser.</button>
  ....
```

Please, can someone explain to me hot to integrate socket.io with koas server? I've installed  ["socket.io": "^1.4.5"]. What are the next steps?

PS: Sory about my ugly english.

Answer (score 1):

I've founded a solution [here](https://github.com/mattstyles/koa-socket). Bellow is a general code sample

```
const Koa = require( 'koa' )
const IO = require( 'koa-socket' )

const app = new Koa()
const io = new IO()

app.use( ... )

io.attach( app )

io.on( 'join', ( ctx, data ) => {
  console.log( 'join event fired', data )
})

app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000 )
```